# Find a number of lines contained with { } that doesn't include a certain string

Tags: java, regex

For our codebase, i need to find all the catch statements that don't print the stacktrace..

So a line like this;

```
catch (Exception e) { }
```

or

```
catch (Exception e) { 
    Do Something
}
```

or

```
 catch (Exception e) {

 }
```

While not including if the string "StackTrace" is included anywhere between the { }

I've this

```
 catch\b\s*\(.*\)\s*\{.*\n*(?!stackTrace).*\n*\}
```

Which seems to be mostly working except for multiple lines..

Can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT: Some examples of failures.. It tends to fail on this;

```
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
```

It works for this

```
} catch (JSONException e) {
        }
```

Comment: What language is your script to do the parsing in?

Comment: Looks to me like the language being scanned is Java, but what is doing the scanning? Some success/fail examples would be nice

Comment: depending on your platform and regex options, . might not match \n. So you seem to be looking for text, followed by \n*, then not "stackTrace", followed by text, followed by \n*. I think you mean the text parts to also include \n's. So to me it would seem you need to say something like "{[.\n]*(?!stackTrace)[.\n]*}

Comment: Unless the code is machine-generated, there is little hope of writing anything satisfactory with a simple regex. Indeed, a full solution must include a Java parser.

Comment: No regular expression will get you 100% since a regular expression cannot pair brackets so you have to be OK with some false positives because the StackTrace string appears after a nested block.

Comment: @glowcoder It's using the native fileSearch of Eclipse, search in .java files

Comment: @Borodin.. I added the examples in my edit in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression to find each `catch(...)` then scan downwards line-by-line, counting open/close braces until the end of the catch block. At each line of the scan using a regex to check for "StatckTrace".

Comment: this is what i had to end up doing

Answer (score 1):

Here is my regex for you (a bit ugly - but it works! Any improvements welcome)

```
catch\s*\([^)]*\)[^{]*\{[^}]*StackTrace[^}]*\}
```

Comment: What if there are curly braces *inside* the catch block?

Comment: Then you would have a problem using regex anyway, you can't balance braces (or anything for that matter) using regex. It is fundamental to its expressive power. So if you also want to analyze this, you'd need something stronger like a context free grammar.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ: I just created a regex for the problem Wonder asked for. You're right - it won't work with additional brackets in {}

Comment: This got me 4 more finds (from 66 to 71) but it's still missing this one " catch (NameNotFoundException e) {\n\n\n\t}" (it's an empty bracket with 3 breaklines)

Comment: Actually this gets me the lines that contain StackTrace, it's supposed to be done for where there's no StackTrace

Comment: @Wonder: oops, I missed that little word 'not'... I'lll work on it

Comment: Haha, thanks! Cuz so you know other than upvote and accept, i can't afford any other currency

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do automated code checking you should look at PMD and checkstyle.

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/

http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/

In fact PMD already has a rule defined for "EmptyCatchBlock"

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/basic.html